# NFS Share with root for anonuid / anongid

Tags: nfs, root, export

I've exported a share from my server and set anonuid and anongid to be 0 (root).  However, when I mount the share on the client, it doesn't appear my settings are working as I'm getting permission denied to folders within the share owned by root.

Server `CentOS 5.7` / Client `CentOS 6.4` using `NFS version 3.2.29.`

Here is my /etc/exports on SERVER:

```
/STORAGE 10.0.5.10(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```

Basically, when the client `(10.0.5.10)` connects to the server, I need it to behave as if it were root on the server.  Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: Check this - http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6345, it should be a bug.

Comment: Thank you!  I made a small mistake in my original post.  The SERVER is CentOS 5.7 and the CLIENT is 6.4.  Assuming the same bug still applies?  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

If you want any user on 10.0.5.10 to appear as root you want to do this:

`/STORAGE 10.0.5.10(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0)`

`all_squash` tells NFS that for any user connecting from 10.0.5.10, ignore their actual UID/GID and instead treat them as if UID=anonuid and GID=anongid. Since you set `anonuid=0,anongid=0` that gives all users on `10.0.5.10` root access privileges on `/STORAGE`, effectively bypassing all security on `/STORAGE` and leaving it wide open to abuse from anyone appearing to come from the 10.0.5.10 IP address.

FWIW, this is a terrible idea from a security point of view.

If you can use NFSv4 on the server, you can enable UID/GID mapping and add a static map to `/etc/idmapd.conf` on the server, telling it that a specific user on 10.0.5.10 should be given root access on the NFSv4 server. `man idmapd.conf` for details on setting up the config file. Once the config file is set up on the NFSv4 server, update your export:

`/STORAGE 10.0.5.10(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`

Then you just want to enable mapping, clear the idmap cache, and restart the map service:

```
echo N > /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
nfsidmap -c
service rpcidmapd restart
```

If you do that, you're only giving one user root access, not all users.

Comment: Although `anonuid=0` is a bad idea, I found this helpful for setting to a different value (default Ubuntu first user added, 1001).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should upgrade to NFS4, as things behave slightly different on each version.

Instead of `no_root_squash` you will need to use `root_squash` or `all_squash` - this is the only relevant parameter regarding this question.

`all_squash` makes any client connected to that share to use the ID given in the `anonuid`/`anongid` parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much! `all_squash` along with `anonuid=33,anonguid=33` is exactly what I was looking for (executing CLI PHP scripts with my "webdev" user, but still writing the files as www-data), but I couldn't (easily, at all) find an answer to my interrogation. Thanks :)